# WindowManagerBadTokenException unable to add window ,is your activity running?

Tags: android

I have an android project, all source code haven't error but sometimes it give me a force close.

---

here is my code:

```
Handler mHanlder = new Handler() {

    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        super.handleMessage(msg);
        switch (msg.what){
            case 0://车主下单
                Toast.makeText(CarOwnerPlaceOrderActivity.this, "下单成功", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                break;
        }
    }
};
 String url = getString(R.string.server_url) + URLMap.COMMIT_CAR_WAY_BILL;
    Http.exchange(HttpRequest.HttpMethod.POST,url,params,mHanlder,PLACEORDER,mContext);
```

---

**HTTP code**

```
public class Http {
private static final String TAG = "Http";
public static CustomProgressDialog customProgressDialog;
public static void exchange(HttpRequest.HttpMethod method, final String url,final RequestParams params, final Handler handler, final int what  ,final Context context){
    HttpUtils httpUtils = new HttpUtils();
    httpUtils.send(method, url, params, new RequestCallBack<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            if (params.getQueryStringParams().size() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < params.getQueryStringParams().size(); i++) {
                    sb.append(params.getQueryStringParams().get(i));
                    if (i + 1 < params.getQueryStringParams().size()) {
                        sb.append("&");
                    }
                }
                LogUtil.Log("url= " + url + sb);
            }
            if (customProgressDialog == null) {
                customProgressDialog = new CustomProgressDialog(context,"加载中...");
            }
            if (url.equals(context.getString(R.string.server_url) + URLMap.ADVIERTISE) || url.equals(context.getString(R.string.server_url) + URLMap.RECOMMENDLIST)){

            } else {
                customProgressDialog.show();
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(ResponseInfo<String> responseInfo) {
            Log.d(TAG + "->" + url, "onSuccess: "+ responseInfo.result);
            customProgressDialog.dismiss();
            try {
                JSONObject data = new JSONObject(responseInfo.result);
                int state = Integer.valueOf(data.getString("state"));
                if (state == 1){
                    Message message = Message.obtain();
                    message.what = what;
                    message.obj = responseInfo.result;
                    handler.sendMessage(message);
                } else {
                    String mess = data.getString("message");
                    Toast.makeText(context, mess, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            } catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }


        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(HttpException e, String s) {
            Log.e(url, "onFailure: " + s);
            customProgressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(context, s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + e.getExceptionCode());
            Log.e(TAG, "onFailure: " + s );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
}
```

**Logcat:**

---

```
android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@148da99e is not valid; is your activity running?
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:562)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:282)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:298)
at cn.com.hailun.HTTP.Http$1.onStart(Http.java:51)
at com.lidroid.xutils.http.HttpHandler.onProgressUpdate(HttpHandler.java:200)
at com.lidroid.xutils.task.PriorityAsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(PriorityAsyncTask.java:385)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:139)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5302)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:950)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
```

**Question**:

---

sometime there is this,sometime does not happen.

---

and，his need Context is activity,I have tried to other Context ,I have tried to ，why？

---

Thanks so much!!

Comment: instead of context, pass the activity reference as a parameter

Comment: The problem is, you're trying to show `customProgressDialog` when the activity is finished. So there will be an  exception.

Comment: @SripadRaj  yes,I know, trying to show customProgressDialog when the activity is finished. But, hanlder.sendMessage  after activity finish, customProgressDialog is dismiss, so, why? And,sometime there is this,sometime does not happen, why?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show your dialog on a finished activity. You can check if it's destroyed with `isDestroyed()` and if it's destroyed do no show the dialog.